# how to use between on an alpha numaric value in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have to use between on distance and find data between two values,
For ex: get all data between distance 30 to 50

```php
$query->whereBetween('distance', [request('km_range')[0], request('km_range')[1]]);
```

database row

| distance column |
| --- |
| 30km |
| 50km |
| 60km |

Comment: Don't store your distances as `'30km'`, store `distance` and `unit` separately, i.e. `distance: 30, unit: 'km'` (or similar). `between` won't work as you're expecting if you're using `'30km'`, since that is a `string` (`varchar` or similar in your database).

Comment: Alternatively, if all the distances are in kilometers, you can save the `distance` as just the integer or float value in the database and in your model set accessors and mutators https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Got it thank you @TimLewis i knew the answer but i was thinking if there is a way to do it. I appreciate your help. Thank you again :)

Comment: Got it thank you @Coola  i was thinking if there is a way to do it. I appreciate your help. Thank you again :)